# Multiprocessing and Socket: "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use"

Tags: sockets, tcp, python-multiprocessing, errno

I utilized a Raspberry Pi and executed my Python script within the Thonny IDE. The script incorporates the Socket Module for data reception from UWB ESP32 devices, which are programmable with Arduino.

With the current OOP python code, I can observe that I resolved the error about "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use" with multiple consecutive trials by adding this line of code after "self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)".

***ADDED LINE***

```
self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Here's the full code for that one. In addition, I am not quite sure if I correctly implement the closing of socket connection. But is working as of now.

***OOP PYTHON CODE***

```
import socket 
import json
import cmath
import os
import time

class UWB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect_network()
        self.line = []
    
    def connect_network(self):
        self.interface = 'wlan0' # Raspberry Pi Network Interface name

        # Get the IP address for the specified interface
        try:
            self.UDP_IP = os.popen(f"ifconfig {self.interface} | grep 'inet ' | awk '{{print $2}}'").read().strip()
            print("***Local IP:" + str(self.UDP_IP) + "*** \n") 
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error at IP: {e}")
        
        self.UDP_PORT = 8080 # Non-priveleged
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.UDP_IP, self.UDP_PORT))
        self.sock.listen(1)

        print("[---STATUS---] Waiting to secure connection... \n")
        self.data, self.addr = self.sock.accept() #
        print("[---STATUS---] Accepted Connection from Foreign IP: " + str(self.addr))

    # Read UWB data from the network and return a list of UWB data
    def read_data(self):     
        self.line = self.data.recv(1024).decode('UTF-8') # Read data from the network socket
        self.uwb_list = []
        try:         
            self.uwb_data = json.loads(self.line)  # Parse the received JSON data    
            self.uwb_list = self.uwb_data["links"] # Extract the "links" field from the JSON data
        except:
            pass
        return self.uwb_list

    def start_uwbProcess(self):
        while True:
            self.line = self.read_data()
            print("line", self.line)
            time.sleep(0.05)

    def get_uwbData(self):
        return self.line

    def uwbClose(self):
        print("Sock Closed")
        self.sock.close()


# Initialization
system = UWB()

try:
    system.start_uwbProcess()
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: {e}")
    system.uwbClose()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("1) System stopped!..")
    system.uwbClose()
finally:
    print("2) System stopped!..")
    system.uwbClose()
```

With that, I tried to call the process and data from class UWB to class ROBOTCONTROLLER. I used the module of multiprocessing with Process and Queue for this one.

However, now I am encountering that error again "OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use". At first, it will connect and the data transferring is okay as what I can produce with the OOP Python Code however after stopping and running the program again, I cant connect to the same port address again.

Here's my current code with multiprocessing.

***MULTIPROCESSING***

```
import socket 
import json
import cmath
import os
import time

class UWB:
    def __init__(self, result_queue):
        self.result_queue = result_queue        
        self.connect_network()
        self.list = []
    
    def connect_network(self):
        self.interface = 'wlan0' # Raspberry Pi Network Interface name
        # Get the IP address for the specified interface
        try:
            self.UDP_IP = os.popen(f"ifconfig {self.interface} | grep 'inet ' | awk '{{print $2}}'").read().strip()
            print("***Local IP:" + str(self.UDP_IP) + "*** \n") 
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error at IP: {e}")
        
        self.UDP_PORT = 8080 # Non-priveleged
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)   
        self.sock.bind((self.UDP_IP, self.UDP_PORT))
        self.sock.listen(1)  # No. of Connected Device

        print("[---STATUS---] Waiting to secure connection... \n")
        self.data, self.addr = self.sock.accept() #
        print("[---STATUS---] Accepted Connection from Foreign IP: " + str(self.addr))

    # Read UWB data from the network and return a list of UWB data
    def read_data(self):     
        self.line = self.data.recv(1024).decode('UTF-8') # Read data from the network socket
        self.uwb_list = []
        try:         
            self.uwb_data = json.loads(self.line)  # Parse the received JSON data    
            self.uwb_list = self.uwb_data["links"] # Extract the "links" field from the JSON data
        except:
            pass
        return self.uwb_list

    def start_uwbProcess(self):
        while True:
            self.list = self.read_data()
            get_uwbData = self.list
            self.result_queue.put(get_uwbData)
            
            time.sleep(0.05)

    def uwbClose(self):
        print("Sock Closed")
        self.sock.close()


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import math
import multiprocessing
import queue
import turtle
import sys
import time

class ROBOTCONTROLLER:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.initialize_pushbuttonMode()
        self.initialize_interfaces()

        # Initializing the debouncing variables
        # For Start
        self.startLastState = True
        self.startLastTime = 0
        # For Resume
        self.resumeLastState = True
        self.resumeLastTime = 0
        # For Debounce Delay in [BUTTONS]
        self.debounceDelay = 50 # Can adjust the debounce delay as needed (in milliseconds)

        self.processState = False
        self.onGoing = False
        self.waitCnt = 0
        #self.isDeliveryComplete = False # Will decide if will removed, due to isTargetAchived in UWBdata

        # Not used Yet
        self.prev_lidar_cycle = 0
        self.prev_uwb_cycle = 0
        ######

        self.cmd = None
        self.lastcmd = None        
    def initialize_pushbuttonMode(self):
        # Initialize PushButton Mode
        print("Setting Up Pushbutton Mode")
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        
    def initialize_interfaces(self):
        self.uwb_result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()       
        self.uwbMultiProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.uwbProcessFunction, args=(self.uwb_result_queue,))          
        self.startMultiProcessing = False
    
    def uwbProcessFunction(self, result_queue):
        self.uwb = UWB(result_queue)
        self.uwb.start_uwbProcess()
        
    def pushbutton_init(self):
        # Define Button pin setting:
        GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN) # START BUTTON: EXTERNAL-PULLUP
        GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN) # RESUME BUTTON: EXTERNAL-PULLUP

    def run(self):
        try:
            # Activating System's Process     
            while True:         
                if not self.processState:
                    # Readings of Start Button
                    curTime = int(time.time() * 1000) # Convert current time to milliseconds
                    startCurState = GPIO.input(5) # Read the current state of the start button               
                    print("CurStart: " + str(startCurState))
                    print("Process: " + str(self.processState)) # Already Initialized in function "def initialize_variables(self)"

                    if startCurState != self.startLastState:
                        self.startLastTime = curTime            
                    if (curTime -  self.startLastTime) > self.debounceDelay:
                        if startCurState == False: #ON
                            print("START BUTTON is PRESSED")
                            self.processState = True #ON
                            print("PROCESSING...")
                        else: #==True OFF
                            print("PRESS the START BUTTON")       
                    self.startLastState = startCurState

                else: #self.processState == True:                       
                    if self.onGoing:
                        self.lidarUWBMultiProcessingCallback()
                        #self.control_center() -> Moved inside lidarUWBMultiProcessingCallback()

                    else:
                        curTime = int(time.time()*1000)
                        resumeCurState = GPIO.input(6)
                        print("CurResume: ", resumeCurState)
                   
                        if resumeCurState != self.resumeLastState:
                            self.resumeLastTime = curTime               
                        if (curTime - self.resumeLastTime) > self.debounceDelay:
                            if resumeCurState == False: # ON
                                print("RESUME BUTTON is PRESSED")
                                self.onGoing = True
                            else:
                                print("PRESS the RESUME BUTTON")
                        self.resumeLastState = resumeCurState
                               
                time.sleep(0.05) #Added for incrementing of cycle counts atomically
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occured: {e}")

    def lidarUWBMultiProcessingCallback(self):
        if not self.startMultiProcessing:
            self.uwbMultiProcess.start()
            self.startMultiProcessing = True
            print("LidarUWBMultiProcessing started.")
        else:
            #print("LidarUWBThread is already running")
            pass
        
        self.control_center()
        
    def control_center(self):
        if not self.uwb_result_queue.empty():
            uwbData = self.uwb_result_queue.get_nowait()  
            print(uwbData)        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Initialization
    robot = ROBOTCONTROLLER()
    robot.pushbutton_init()
   
    # Activating System's Process
    robot.run()
```

I tried to run again to run the OOP Python Code again but if I tried to run the code with multiprocessing code fisrt, OOP python code isn't connecting also but if vice versa, when the OOP python code is runs first, it connects smoothly before running multiprocessing code.

When the error shows, my only solution is to restart my raspberry pi which is very time-consuming. Here's the traceback below.

***MULTIPROCESSING TRACEBACK***

```
 RESUME BUTTON is PRESSED
 LidarUWBMultiProcessing started.
 ***Local IP:192.168._.___*** 
 
 Process Process-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
     self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "/home/rome/Desktop/MP_UWB_INPROGRESS2.py", line 105, in uwbProcessFunction
     self.uwb = UWB(result_queue)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/home/rome/Desktop/MP_UWB_INPROGRESS2.py", line 11, in __init__
     self.connect_network()
   File "/home/rome/Desktop/MP_UWB_INPROGRESS2.py", line 26, in connect_network
     self.sock.bind((self.UDP_IP, self.UDP_PORT))
 OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Hoping for any response that can help me fix this one. Thanks.

Comment: Why are your variables named UDP when you’re using TCP? And why aren’t you binding to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I just got it from a source code which already uses UWB but I know that I am in TCP (just didnt change it) when i type "netstat -tuln" in Raspberry Pi (RPI) terminal.

RPI and UWB ESP32 is connected to the same WiFi.

For a UWB ESP32 device to connect to Raspberry Pi, I need to use the IP and Port that the Raspberry Pi is using in the Arduino code for it to send data and for the python script to receive that data.

I still didn't try to use 0.0.0.0 because I don't know yet why should I. Will it have a great impact with socket on a multiprocessing environment?

Comment: It will make it possible to connect to the socket from any IP address. You could always just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got resolved the issue using this command in RPI terminal

```
fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

and use subprocess module for this to be called in my python script with retry functionality.